# How to deploy stuff onto AWS EC2 instance using Jenkins without using AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

At our employers place, we can't use AWS CodeDeploy, CodeBuild and CodePipeline.
Using only Jenkins which is on Prem server, I am able to create a CI/CD pipeline to run Terraform (infratstucture scripting) scripts and provisioned EC2 instances. Once those instances come up, I want run another CI/CD pipeline in Jenkins (on prem server) to deploy binaries onto those Ec2 instances.

is it possible in Jenkins to deploy stuff onto Ec2 instances?

thank you

Comment: Yes, you can put artifacts/binaries on EC2 from connected on-premise network. But, the deployment tools and logic varies, based on what you are going to deploy on EC2. such as docker image, jar, ear, exe, RPM, war and other types of binary files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are pushing your deployable artifacts/binaries in S3( if not your Jenkins pipeline can copy the artifacts to S3 buckets).

During the provisioning, you can easily install a daemon(small shell scrip) on the newly built instances to pull the binaries from S3 as soon as they are available(as these are new instances, doing this at the same time on all the instances should be ok)

I am not sure of the complications you are facing, I would simply use [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for installing the new binaries on all new instances. One step shorter.

[aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance) terraform provider has the option for the same.

[cloud-init](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-init)

You can checkout [AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/index.html) as well for automating your workflow.

Comment: Mine is windows EC2 instances. can I use "Userdata" to pull binaries from S3 bucket and put them onto the EC2 instances?

Comment: @Jason as per the documentation [Run commands on your Windows instance at launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) yes.